# Swap Ctrls and Capslock for remote access sessions using AHK for Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, remote-desktop

I am using computers campus wide to access a Windows 7 desktop machine in my office and I am having trouble with swapping `CapsLock` and `Ctrl` key.

The problem is that, I only have admin privilege on the machine in my office, and I have swapped `CapsLock` and `Ctrl` through editing the registry (`regedit`) by adding a proper "Scancode Map".

However, this does not help in any of the remote-access sessions, since `CapsLock` on the local machine remains as is.

I resorted to AHK, but setting `CapsLock::LControl` in scripts running on both machine does not solve the problem. Upon specifying the key-swap through AHK, pressing `CapsLock` does send a `Ctrl`-keystroke to the RDP session. However, at the local machine, the light for "CapsLock" shall also turn on (or turn off)! This indicates that, while AHK is converting a press of `CapsLock` to be `Ctrl`, the local machine takes it as an original pressing of `CapsLock`. Furthermore, pressing `Ctrl` several time will confuse AHK and end up with termination of the process.

I also tried to set the following in the script running on the local machine, but it does not help.

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
#IfWinActive, Remote Desktop
    SetCapsLockState, off
#IfWinActive
; or
#IfWinActive, ahk_class TscShellContainerClass
    SetCapsLockState, off
#IfWinActive
```

What should I do to consistently specify the key-swap between `CapsLock` and `Ctrl` on the remotely-accessed machine, when I don't have admin-right at local machine? On my own laptop where I had also swapped `CapsLock` and `Ctrl` through registry, there is no problem with swapping those keys in remote-access sessions.

All the best,

-Linfeng

Comment: Try [#InstallKeybdHook](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InstallKeybdHook.htm).

Comment: I tried to insert the following line into the AHK script running on my local machine, but `Capslock` key is still functional. `SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff`

Comment: @wOxxOm, I have also added the hook, by putting the following line at the beginning of the AHK script. `#InstallKeybdHook`; however, this still is not helpful. The `CapsLock` key is still active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to use `uncap` together with `AutoHotKey` to fix this.

uncap's GitHub: https://github.com/susam/uncap

1. run `AutoHotKey` script on local machine
2. download `uncap` on remote machine
3. run on PowerShell

`path\to\uncap.exe 0x14:0x14 0x14:0xa2`

this will override the default behaviour so it doesn't render you Esc useless

see [here](https://github.com/susam/uncap#usage) for detail

---

More practically, one can put the following three files into a thumb drive and carry it around. (UCA not tested given the current StayHome order. Some school computer may ban `*.exe` files from running completely?)

1. `uncap.exe`, downloaded from [here](https://github.com/susam/uncap/releases/download/0.3.0/uncap.exe). Or, refer to the [Github repo for uncap](https://github.com/susam/uncap#usage) an up-to-date installer.
2. Bat file 1 to trigger the remapping. Call it `Swap_Capslock_and_Ctrl.bat`. And, put the following content:

```
.\uncap.exe 0x14:0xa2 0xa2:0x14
```

3. Bat file 2, to stop the script. Call it `StopScript.bat`, with contents:

```
.\uncap.exe -k
```

Comment: Looks promising. I will try the `uncap 0x14:0xa2 0xa2:0x14` that is meant for swapping Caps Lock key and Left Control key.

Answer (score 2):

## Low-tech solution

### The struggle

After struggling for hours on **how to swap <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>** in vain, I figured out that there may not be an ideal solution. (Ideal at the level of creating a `scancode` mapping using administrator privileges.)

### The solution

I ended up buying a mechanical keyboard with DIP switch, and this solves all my struggles with softly re-mapping the keys through AHK script. The DIP switch sort of "re-wired" the keyboard to have the key <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> behave as it is a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

This AutoHotkey script uses workarounds to provide pretty good keyboard functionality to make <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> behave like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with no button blinking. Basically <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> etc become a two-stage process, hold down capslock, then press the letter, but it can become quite smooth.

```
;===============
;workaround script, pretty good functionality, no capslock blinking
CapsLock::
vIsCtrlOn := 1
Return

$a::
$b::
$c::
$d::
$e::
$f::
$g::
$h::
$i::
$j::
$k::
$l::
$m::
$n::
$o::
$p::
$q::
$r::
$s::
$t::
$u::
$v::
$w::
$x::
$y::
$z::
vLetter := SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 1-1)
if vIsCtrlOn
SendInput ^%vLetter%
else
SendInput %vLetter%
vIsCtrlOn := 0
Return
;===============
```

I provide some notes on testing that might help the OP and other AutoHotkey users:

```
;===============
;script with just these 3 lines, no capslock blinking
CapsLock::
SendInput {Enter}
Return
;===============

;===============
;script with just these 7 lines, capslock blinking
CapsLock::
SendInput {Enter}
Return

CapsLock & c::
SendInput ^c
Return
;===============
```

[EDIT:]
This additional AutoHotkey script will display the capslock on/off status:

```
vFormat := "zh0 b1 c0 fs18 x1000 y100 w150"
Loop
{
if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")
vText := "capslock on"
else
vText := "capslock off"
if !(vText = vText2)
Progress, %vFormat%, %vText%
vText2 := vText
Sleep 100
}
Return
```

Comment: Hi @vafylec, I have tried to deploy the script you mentioned above as an executable on the public computers in my school, and sadly, it does not completely solve the problem. Now, the indicator light for Capslock is no longer informative, and I am lost at which key I was at. I am posting my low-tech solution to the original problem, which I satisfactory enough for my particular use-case.

Comment: Hi @llinfeng, I am glad that my script could still have been
of potential use to you after these many months,
and it's great to hear the feedback from you.
-- Btw if the only problem is that you have no way
of knowing if CapsLock is on or not,
I've added a script that can display this.
Which I would run as a separate script/application.

Comment: Hi @vafylec, thanks a lot for your new edits; I will test out once I make it to the school; the goal I had in mind is simple: to be able to fire an AHK script, that swaps the Capslock and Ctrl keys on a machine that I have no admin rights, and make the swap valid **in remote access session**. So far, I was bothered with the unstable performance of the swaps. (Sometimes, the Capslock shall be held down; in other cases, Ctrl key is not released.) SO, I turned to get a keyboard with DIP switch instead.